# Sync same folder between two OSs

Tags: backup, google-drive

I have three partitions: the first one has Windows 10 installed. The second one also has Windows 10 installed, just for testing purposes. The third one is my storage partition, with Documents, Images and Desktop folders, shared between these two OSs.

When I set google drive to sync my Documents folder in both OSs, two backups are created. What I want is to create just one backup for the same Documents folder. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mklink command in windows to share the two folders. With this commmand "mklink /J C:\FolderOnPartition1 C:\FolderOnPartition2", every file you put in 1 folder wil show in the other. And vice versa.